# Why would the last column in my SlickGrid wrap out of view (or into next row) only in Firefox?

Tags: slickgrid

For some reason, the last column in some of my SlickGrids is wrapping out of view or into the next row.  Playing with the widths of my container and columns, or removing all the other CSS from my site, doesn't fix it.  It seems like because of padding and other such things the canvas element of the grid is 1 pixel too thin for Firefox's liking.  I was able to get it working by changing the setCanvasWidth in slickgrid so that it adds 1 to the width that's trying to be set.

I don't experience this on any of the SlickGrid demos though.  But I'm not doing anything unusual.  Any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the browser text zoom level.

Comment: Wow, that was it!  I didn't realize that I had accidentally zoomed out.  And since most people will be zooming in, not out, I don't think I have to worry about this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but did have to change the `.grid-canvas` width in `slick.grid.css` as this was defaulting to 500px. CSS is now

```
.grid-canvas {
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Warning: this is not functional if you use the `fullWidthRows` option.